# Pro Micro board not responding to anything

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

I just got a couple of Arduino Pro Micros for a [custom keyboard](https://github.com/omkbd/ErgoDash) build. Before testing them with the Arduino IDE, I tried to test them with [qmk](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware) by shorting `RST` to `GND` to try and flash it. After a few seconds of holding `RST`, I got a single blink and nothing else, and qmk didn't seem to have detected the reset.

I've tried setting "Board" to "Arduino Micro" and "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini". I'm on Arch Linux and no matter which USB port is plugged in, the IDE only shows `/dev/ttyS0`). I tried uploading the "Blink" example, as well as "Burn Bootloader", but only got `programmer is not responding` like so:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyS0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: If RESET is connected to GND then the Arduino is going to do nothing. Nothing at all. Nada. It'll be like it's not even there. ttyS0 is the internal UART of your PC (it may not even have a connector...).

Comment: activate the bootloader with a double reset. Micro is not Mini. for "burn bootloader" you need a programmer hardware

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to use the port `ttyACM0` (and not `ttyS0`) which wasn't found at the time. The port was there the next day and I have no idea why it wasn't there before.

Also, I thought I had to press and hold `RST` for a couple of seconds to reset the Pro Micro, but I actually have to press it twice in a row.

I've managed to flash the firmware for my keyboard by double-pressing `RST`.

Comment: the sketch handles the usb, without working sketch there is no USB and the bootloader must be activated to handle USB